# django-STATICFILES _DIRS not collecting

Tags: python, django, server, static, django-staticfiles

In my django project settings, I defined my static files like so:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR +'/folder1',
    BASE_DIR + '/folder2',
]
```

But collectstatic doesn't collect what is defined in "STATICFILES_DIRS".

Even though it works locally, on the server it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the BASE_DIR by print it ... it could be the problem

Comment: `on the server it doesn't work` with debug=false or true? `collectstatic doesn't collect` show output log of this command

Comment: @MahmoudNasser print output is directly pointing to the project's main directory which is correct.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I set debug to True, restarted gunicorn with no success. Then tried it again with debug=False, no success also.

Comment: Django does not serve static files with `debug=false`. no point of testing in this mode.

Comment: @IvanStarostin my production server is "gunicorn"; I restarted it but the result is still the same.

Comment: Just to note: my BASE_DIR is: 

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: It was obviously an NGINX issue, please check your configuration if you face such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem after checking my NGINX config file.
Now everything works good.